# Error on local machine but not on production server

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Can someone help me with this error ? this throws on 4 of 5 developer boxes and does not (fortunatelly) on production enviroment, yet no idea why.

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for
>   a Decimal.   at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles
>   options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String
>   value, IFormatProvider provider)   at
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider) 
>   at System.Convert.ToDecimal(Object value)   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)   at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 ordinal)   ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)   at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetTypedValueDefault(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal)   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal)   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2
>   constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
>
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)   at
>   Glocalapps.BusinessLogic.Logic.ProductLogic.GetProductManagementCatalogData(Int32
>   idCatalog, Int32 skip, Int32 take, String name, Nullable`1 isActive,
>   Nullable`1 isVisible, Nullable`1 revised)

Comment: Looks like a data problem to me. Are you sure all devs use the same dbschema with the same data? Backup a working db and restore on another non-working box and see if it reproduces....

Comment: @rene same dbschema, same data, retored on a non-working box and still doesn't work...

Comment: International settings the same?

Comment: @rene same. Also changed culture on threads to see if I get different results with no luck

Comment: By the looks of it you're using a MySql client. I'm not sure if my.cnf is in play, but if it is you might check those. I recall they can do per connection settings for encoding and i8n

Comment: @rene thanks. Worth looking at these. I'll let you know if I find something

Comment: You could try to enable tracing to see what is different http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing.html